# Use variable inside a call?

Tags: php

Is there a way to make this happen? I mean where the stage == to a variable?

```
$var1 = "1";
$var2 = "2";    
$where = $db->query('SELECT * FROM stages WHERE stage = $var1');
$chapter = $where[0]["$var1"];
```

Edit: Got told to give more information. 
When I try to run this I get a php error for the databaseProvider and nothing happens. If I write

```
$where = $db->query('SELECT * FROM stages WHERE stage = 1');
$chapter = $where[0]["1"];
```

Everything works fine. I just want to be able to automate those two ones :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is a little short on information, what problems have you run into?

Comment: I'm assuming you're using PDO...

Comment: you cannot put a variable into a string defined with single quotes. It should work with outer double quotes but you should not do it like this with variables from a http-request because of possible sql injection. Use PDO prepare statements for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use double-quotes instead of single-quotes then PHP will interpolate your variable for you:

```
$var1 = "1";
$var2 = "2";    
$where = $db->query("SELECT * FROM stages WHERE stage = $var1");
```

But if $var1 is something that comes from user in put then you shouldn't do this to avoid SQL injection.

I'm unclear where your `$where[0]["$var1"]` was going... Do you mean to then use another variable? If so, you're looking for prepared statements using `:var` in PDO or `?` in mysqli.

Comment: If you'll edit your question with a little more detail we can try to help you with the rest -- unless this has really answered your question, in which case please do mark it as the accepted answer...